# SOAPUI - REST request multipart/mixed - how to add attachment

Tags: soapui, multipart, mixed

I am trying to test RESTful service which is configured to consume multipart/mixed using soapui tool.

```
@POST
@Path("requestXmlAndAttachment")
@Consumes({ "multipart/mixed" })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public ResponseTO processRequestXmlAndAttachment(final       com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart     multiPartRequest) {
 // application logic
```

}

Within SOAPUI, I have setup REST resourse and added 2 parameters, first file pointing to request xml and second file with data (I selected style PLAIN from dropdown).

```
File1       file:request.xml
File2       file:datafile.xls
```

On SOAPUI request editor window I have selected multipart/mixed for media type.  When I submit request to the server I do not see that files are being attached to the request.  Here is what can be viewed on the server log:

```
Feb 7, 2013 1:36:58 PM com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter filter
INFO: 56 * Server in-bound request
56> POST http://localhost:7001/myservice/requestXmlAndAttachment
56 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
56 > Content-Type: multipart/mixed
56 > Content-Length: 0
56 > Host: localhost:7001
56 > Connection: Keep-Alive
56 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
56 >
```

As you can see Content-Length is 0.
I have been able to test this service from java junit program.  Here is the portion of the program:

```
BodyPart bp1 = new BodyPart();
bp1.setEntity(requestXMLString);
bp1.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

BodyPart bp2 = new BodyPart();
bp2.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.type("file").fileName("datafaile.xls").build  ());
bp2.setEntity(binaryData1);
bp2.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);


MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart().bodyPart(bp1).bodyPart(bp2);

ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
Client client = Client.create(cc);
WebResource webResource = client.resource ("http://localhost:7001/myservice/requestXmlAndAttachment");
ClientResponse response = webResource.type(new MediaType("multipart", "mixed")).post(ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```

I have also tried to change media type to multipart/formdata (just to experiment) on SOAP UI Request editor box, then I can see that Content-Length = 30654 and I see file content read on the server logs.

I have also experimented adding http headers to the request (MIME-Version, etc), but it did not make any difference.

Although I can unit test without SOAPUI, I would prefer to have this test working with SOAPUI, because I already have bunch of the other tests setup in soapui executing different methods in the same service.

Is there anyway to use SOAP UI for testing multipart/mixed with attachments?
Thanks in advance for looking into it.

Comment: SoapUI, currently, will only add the attachments if the mediaType is exactly "multipart/form-data". There is an issue for this in SmartBear's issues tracking system, feel free to contact us regarding a resolution for this problem: SOAPUI-4653

Comment: Renato, thanks for getting back to me.  Do you plan to have support for multipart/mixed in the future?

Comment: Yes, but we cannot promise when... it will depend on how prioritized this issue will get...